# Why is there a right margin next to my right frame?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a left and a right frame. For some reason I have a very small margin on the right side of my frame.

I think the reason why is because my right frame has a width of 29% and my left frame has a margin of 70%. Giving it a total of %99 . But for some reason when I set my right frame to 30% it site below the right frame.

Can anyone please help me so that the right  frame will take up the whole screen size with out any marging

Thank you!!!

Below is my HTML code and a link to the actual website (please not this is just a skeleton mock up of another project I am trying to implement this to.

http://15c04752.ngrok.com/sandbox/frames/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

<style>

    body,html{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;

    }
    iframe{

        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .left{
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .right {
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }


</style>


</head>
<body>



<iframe class="left" width="70%" src="left_frame.html"></iframe>

<iframe class="right" src="right_frame.html"  width="29%" name="right_frame"></iframe>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the issue is the white space between the two frames.

There are many ways to remove it, commenting out the white space is a quick one:

```
<iframe width="70%"></iframe><!--
--><iframe width="30%"></iframe>
```

OR (note how the ending `>` of the first `frame` is on the next line)

```
<iframe width="70%"></iframe
><iframe width="30%"></iframe>
```

OR (Removing the white space by having the elements immediately after each other)

```
<iframe width="70%"></iframe><iframe width="30%"></iframe>
```

OR Floating the elements if it's an option, because floating the elements will take them out from the normal height calculation of the parent.

```
<iframe width="70%"></iframe>
<iframe width="30%"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
iframe {float:left;}
```

OR
setting the `font-size` of the parent, in your case `body`, to `0` then setting it back again to the needed value for the children

Comment: Wow Arbel. I didn't even realize that. I did remove the white space and set it 30% and that did work....

The one thing I am confused about is i thought white space is not parsed in HTML?

Comment: White space is parsed in html, and the way that it is handled can be controlled by the white-space property for each element. What you refer to is the default behavior which is collapsing consequent white spaces in the markup or the html to one white space and then treating it as `white-space:normal;`.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Makes sense. Thank you for providing a great explanation!